# How to set Numeric value on cell that has a formula using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for Java to set Numeric value on a cell that has a formula.

```
double annualizedAmount = 100;
cell.setCellFormula(null);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
cell.setCellValue(annualizedAmount);
```

It sets the value but I get the below error when I open the downloaded excel file.

[image]

How can I get successfully set a numeric value on the cell that has a formula?

Comment: Why not just set the formula to "=100" ???

Comment: I get the same error as above when I do that.

Comment: Are you setting a correct cell type ? I think it should be `cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);`. Not sure

Comment: I need to convert the cell to a Numeric type cell. So I used,
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);  
cell.setCellValue(annualizedAmount);  
And I get Removed records: formula from /xl/text.xml part (calculation properties) when I open the file

Comment: @Hasi007: There normally is not a `/xl/text.xml` part. The removing message may be `Removed records: formula from /xl/calcChain.xml part (calculation properties) `. But apache poi normally updates `/xl/calcChain.xml` if a formula is replaced with a value. So nobody can reproduce your issue from the 4 code lines you have shown. Please show a minimal complete example where the issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Set cell type as below :

```
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
```